# Different front page template for different domains

Tags: 7, theming, domain-access

I have Drupal 7 installation with the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module.

I need to have different page--front.tpl.php templates for some of the subdomains, for example:

www.example.com should have one type of the front page template (not a node, but some custom blocks and module outputs) and d1.example.com, d2.example.com and d3.example.com should have different kind of blocks, module outputs, forms, and template.

The style for the rest of the site should be pretty much the same for all domains.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) and the [Delta](https://www.drupal.org/project/delta) modules to achieve this.

You can create a new instance of a theme using delta module and use context to use that instance for a specific module.

Alternatively, you can use Domain theme module (sub module of Domain module).

Let me know if you get stuck.